# emacs 256 colour support

Tags: emacs

I am using ubuntu 9.04 and GNU Emacs 22.2.1

I am using the terminal to load emacs i.e. `emacs -nw`

However, I am only running in 8 colours.

```
M-X list-colors-display
```

Only displays 8 colours.

In the terminal I run this command

`tput colors` and I get 8 displayed

How can I get full 256 colour support?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just testing on my Debian machine, I get the same as you (8 colours).

You don't say whether you are using an xterm, but in my xterm I have typed

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

and then  `emacs -nw` followed by `list-colors-display` shows 256 colours.

Comment: Also works in an alias, like in `alias e='TERM=xterm-256color emacs -nw'`. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonA.Eugster You probably want to add `TERM=xterm-256color` in your bashrc, as many apps depend on this to use 256 color.

Comment: Note that putting TERM=something into your shell initialization as suggested by @SimonA.Eugster is not a good idea if (!) you're using a terminal multiplexer such as screen or tmux (or byobu) because they have their own terminal capabilities.