# emacs:highlight the current line by underline it

Tags: emacs

In vim, we can use "set cursorline" in dotvim file to turn it on. Is there a way to do this in emacs?

Answer (score 22):

In your .emacs, customize the face for `hl-line-mode`, with something like:

```
(global-hl-line-mode 1)
(set-face-attribute hl-line-face nil :underline t)
```

`hl-line-face` is a variable that stores the name of the [face](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Faces.html) `hl-line-mode` uses to show the current line.  You can customize the `:foreground` `:background` and a bunch of other attributes to your liking.  Check the docs [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Face-Attributes.html).

The `global-hl-line-mode` turns on highlighting the current line in all buffers.  If you just want it in some buffers, turn it on with <kbd>M-x hl-line-mode</kbd>.

Answer (score 14):

There is a good blog post about this topic: [M-x all-things-emacs](http://emacsblog.org/2007/04/09/highlight-the-current-line/)

The following code (enter wit M-: or in ~/.emacs) uses the RGB code #222 as background color (*if* you are in [256-color mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623859/emacs-256-colour-support)!) and underlines the font on the current line. Unsetting the foreground color uses the default color, this e.g. preserves the C++ colours on the highlighted line.

```
(global-hl-line-mode 1)
(set-face-background 'highlight "#222")
(set-face-foreground 'highlight nil)
(set-face-underline-p 'highlight t)
```

You can check whether you need to change `highlight` or (afaik older) `hl-line` with M-x and:

```
describe-face <RET> highlight
describe-face <RET> hl-line
```

This command shows you all settings of the font face used for highlighting the current line. You should get an output like this:

```
Face: highlight (sample) (customize this face)
Documentation:
Basic face for highlighting.

        Family: unspecified
       Foundry: unspecified
         Width: unspecified
        Height: unspecified
        Weight: unspecified
         Slant: unspecified
    Foreground: unspecified
    Background: #222
     Underline: t
      Overline: unspecified
Strike-through: unspecified
           Box: unspecified
       Inverse: unspecified
       Stipple: unspecified
          Font: unspecified
       Fontset: unspecified
       Inherit: unspecified
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an exact equivalent built in.  You can use hl-line-mode to highlight the current line, and customising that mode lets you set the highlighting to be underlining rather than the default different background colour -- but the underline you get stops at the end of the text in the line, rather than continuing to the edge of the window.