# EMACS 24 Arch linux not supporting 256 color

Tags: linux, emacs, 256color

I have looked all over and tried many things but I still can't get 256 color support in EMACS 24.

I tried this: [emacs 256 colour support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623859/emacs-256-colour-support)

But it doesn't work for me.

I have 256 color support in vim and in the terminal but not for emacs.

```
tput colors
```

output 256

but when I do list-colors-display in emacs it only shows 8

Current Setup:

Manjaro Linux (Arch Based)

guake terminal

zsh -> alias e='TERM=xterm-256color emacs -nw'

tmux

Comment: What is your TERM normally set to? Are you running under screen or tmux?

Comment: yes I'm running in tmux..my question has most of my setup

Comment: try "TERM=xterm-256color tmux attach -d -t ${SESSION}" and then test the display with colortest-256 before launching emacs

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with tmux because the TERM environment when I entered tmux was xterm and not xterm-256color. Once I fixed that emacs was fine.

Also colortest-256 is a handy tool for testing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this in `.bashrc`:

```
# 256 colors Tmux, "force tmux to assume the terminal supports 256 colours"
# See man tmux
alias tmux='tmux -2'

export TERM=xterm-256color
```

And in your `.emacs`:

```
;; "Terminal initialization function for screen."
;; Use the xterm color initialization code.
(load "term/xterm")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert this line in your `~/.Xresources` file :

```
xterm*termName: xterm-256color
```

See archlinux wiki for more info : [Xterm - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xterm#TERM_Environmental_Variable)

According to this page [Hidden gems of xterm - Lukáš Zapletal](http://lukas.zapletalovi.com/2013/07/hidden-gems-of-xterm.html#colors), setting `TERM` variable manually is a bad practice.