# Color mode issue in CONEMU -> cygwin -> EMACS

Tags: emacs, cygwin, conemu

when im running EMACS from cygwin which in turn run from ConEmu,dosent  display the emacs color themes.

but if i run the same configuration without conemu i can see the themes displayed properly.

how i can i setup my conEmu to display the 256 color properly and to show all the color themes in EMACs.

My Setup:

```
Environment: Windows 7
Command Prompt : ConEmu 
emulator : cygwin
editor : EMACs
```

Edit: I have used

```
alias emacs='TERM=xterm-256color emacs'
```

after which the ConEMU shows the windows with blank space inbetween. works well in cygwin prompt.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running emacs in a console window, it likely is using termcap/terminfo.  In that case, it pays attention to the $TERM environment variable.  Perhaps when you setup your coneum+cygwin configuration, the $TERM value is not the same as the other way you set it up.

Technically, termcap does not support 256-colors, so whatever $TERM emacs would use is a compromise (special value that just happens to work).  This is mentioned in the ncurses FAQ: [Why not make "xterm" equated to "xterm-256color"?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_256color)

Some programs (such as PuTTY) allow one to set environment variables for their process.  I do not see that in ConEmu's [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/ConEmuEnvironment).  If it lacks that capability, I suppose you could set TERM as needed in your Windows environment, or in your .bashrc

On the general topic of Emacs with 256colors:

- [Terminal emacs colors only work with TERM=xterm-256color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617458/terminal-emacs-colors-only-work-with-term-xterm-256color)
- [emacs 256 colour support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623859/emacs-256-colour-support)

There is a hint in ConEmu's [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/VimXterm) which may be useful: it states that

> Vim's executable must be named ‘vim.exe’;

which makes me suspect that ConEmu has some special feature which looks for this particular name when these other two configuration settings (from the wiki) are set:

> Check options ‘[Inject ConEmuHk](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/ConEmuHk)’ and ‘ANSI X3.64 / xterm 256 colors’ on [Features](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/SettingsFeatures) page;
>   Check option ‘TrueMod (24bit color) support’ on [Colors](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/SettingsColors) page;

If that is so, you could try a workaround, by

- renaming `emacs.exe` to `vim.exe`
- adding a batch file named `emacs.bat`, containing

  `@echo off`

  `emacs.exe %*`

If you happen to have a `vim.exe` already around, it is possible to fixup the batch file to use the actual pathname of `emacs.exe` (but this should be enough to start investigating a workaround).

Comment: i enabled the 256 color mode, after which it runs like a charm in cygwin tty... but same config i.e updating cygwin (which was running on conemu) to 256 color mode, didn't work.

Comment: But you did not comment on what the value of $TERM was.  Likely the working configuration has TERM set to xterm-256color.  (As noted, the regular definition for that will not work with *termcap*, but some packagers have a cut-down version which "works", e.g., using the capabilities matching t_AB and t_AF in the example cited for vim).

Comment: updated the question: i updated $TERM , after doing this only i was able to see 256 colors in cygwin also, before that it supported only 8 color mode. but when i load cygwin through conEMU i get to see black dark empty line in between each line.

Comment: Have you checked your solution of that is only your suppositions?

Comment: I offered it as a possible workaround.  Perhaps you can explain why it will not work.  That would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Cygwin or Msys do not support 256 colors in ConEmu**. They do not know that ConEmu can process xterm-256 and they do processing internally. Of course they bumps into standard console limitation of 16 colors.

Read more in [wiki1](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/CygwinAnsi), [wiki2](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/CygwinMsys).

I know only one application - **[official](http://www.vim.org/download.php)** Vim - which can be [configured](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/VimXterm) to use xterm-256 in ConEmu.

Comment: Wiki contains no information relevant to this question.

Comment: In particular, the comments about vim do not give the reader enough information to understand what issue is being addressed.

Comment: HI Maximus, tnx for the reference, i had come across this VIM hack couple of days back, but i was not able to do the same for emacs. Both VI and EMACS are term editor right, so can a similar hack be done with EMACs.

Comment: The two ConEmu wiki entries contradict each other: either Vim (and other termcap applications) can be configured to work with cygwin+conemu) or they cannot.  Or perhaps (if so, the wiki should be improved), ConEmu has hard-coded behavior to know about "vim.exe" (?)

Comment: @ThomasDickey If you read my answer and wiki carefully you will understand there is no any contradiction. Hint: *official* vim is not build with cygwin.

Comment: Adding more information to the wiki is a constructive way of addressing the problem.

Comment: @ThomasDickey wiki already has all possible information. Unless you can help write that "constuctive information" - I do not think it even can exists.